# How do I split a string using Smalltalk using space as the delimiter

Tags: smalltalk

I have string like "Hello World". I need to split this string to `Hello`, World`` using space delimiter in Smalltalk.

In Java the code looks as follows

```
 String message = "Hello world"
 message.split(' ');
```

How do I do this in Smalltalk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closer to Java:

```
'Hello World' splitOn: Character space.
```

also works with:

```
'Hello World' splitOn: ' '.
```

or (more funky):

```
[ :each | each isSeparator  ] split: 'Hello World'.

'Hello World' splitOn: [ :each | each isSeparator  ].
```

Answer (score 4):

```
| message parts |
message := 'Hello world'.
parts := message substrings. "this is an array"
Transcript
  show: parts first;
  show: parts last
```

Or to define delimiter: `message substrings: ' '`

Comment: After splitting I need I need to print Hello and world separately. Is it possible?

Comment: @Ijaz of course it is. Just access firs and second indexes of the returned array with `at: 1`, `at: 2`, `first`, `second`, `last`…

Comment: sorry First time I'm seeing small talk. Please help me on this

Comment: @Ijaz no, the thing that you've wrote is a complete nonsense. I've changed the answer to hint you, but before proceeding get familiar with smalltalk syntax. It's not as huge as in java http://files.pharo.org/media/flyer-cheat-sheet.pdf

Comment: You could also use `Character space split: message` to split the string.

Answer (score 1):

in a very buggy version of smalltalk on another site, this works but spliton does not.

```
s := 'Hello World' substrings '\n'.
n := s at: 2.

Transcript show: 's at 2='.
Transcript show: n.
Transcript show: ''; cr.
```